# Ubuntu samba share strange permissions on directories drwxrwsr-x

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba

I have strange permission on my samba server.

**smb.conf**

```
[share]
path=/samba/share
valid users = admin share @share
writable = yes
browseable = yes
read only = no
security = user
netbios name = FFshare
create mask = 0664
force create mode = 0664
directory mode = 0775
force directory mode = 0755
force use = admin
force group = share
```

But all new directories that I create have strange permissions

```
drwxrwsr-x
```

What does it mean?
I suppose this capital "S" drwxrw**s**r-x means - setuid?
But how does it apply to a directory?

What is wrong with my settings?  How should smb.conf look like for use with Windows clients with a password request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "s" is in the group permissions, not in owner permissions, so it's **setgid**, not setuid.

Setgid bit for a directory means that everything created within this directory will have the group set to the same group as the directory (and not to the default group of the creator, as it is normally).

I guess Samba needs this setting to operate, and nothing is wrong with your settings :)

Comment: Just as a follow up: If you run `testparm -s` you will see that you have some things that don't belong in a share definition ( netbios name and security ) and that there is no such thing as "force use". I think you meant "force user". Also check the permissions on the target: `ls -dl /samba/share`. I don;t think samba is doing this I think you set the setgid bit on the /samba/share folder.